# PHP JSON not decoding properly

Tags: php, json

I'm trying top decode this JSON data with PHP, but it's not returning anything:

```
{ "message" : "",
  "result" : [ { "Ask" : 0.040400209999999999,
        "BaseVolume" : 456.53976963999997,
        "Bid" : 0.040200010000000001,
        "Created" : "2014-12-19T03:48:49.13",
        "High" : 0.044610999999999998,
        "Last" : 0.040400199999999997,
        "Low" : 0.037999999999999999,
        "MarketName" : "BTC-XPY",
        "OpenBuyOrders" : 194,
        "OpenSellOrders" : 520,
        "PrevDay" : 0.042073039999999999,
        "TimeStamp" : "2014-12-30T02:45:32.983",
        "Volume" : 11072.491576779999
      } ],
  "success" : true
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$pricejson = file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-xpy');
$price = json_decode($pricejson, true);
echo $price->result->Last;
```

When I open the php file containing this code, there's nothing. If I use `echo $pricejson`, I get the whole thing printed out so I definitely have the data.

What is wrong?

Comment: If you haven't already tried, 1) Put `ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);error_reporting(E_ALL);` prior to the decode. 2) Re-check the docs.;; @prodigitalson 's answer should help, but enabling error reporting is usually the easiest way to find the CAUSE of a problem (and thus the solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to json_decode forces all objects to be parsed as associative arrays so you need to access it with array notation. Additionally `result` is an array always so you need to loop over it or access it by index:

```
$price = json_decode($pricejson, true);
// print the first price
echo $price['result'][0]['Last'];

// print all prices:
foreach ($price['result'] as $data) {
   echo $data['Last'];
}
```

Or if you want a mix of objects/arrays then:

```
$price = json_decode($pricejson);
echo $price->result[0]->Last;

// print all prices:
foreach ($price->result as $data) {
   echo $data->Last;
}
```

In top of this its possible there is a json parse error. You might also need to make sure that the JSON you get back is being parsed properly.